# Someone scrambled my calling sign- who am I?

Tags: cipher

Before I left the scene of the crime I left my calling sign... But on the news the next morning all that was left was the following:

```
  .Iaaabmmnt
```

**Which seems to be what I wrote**, but not **how** I wrote it!

```
belacgjfdikh
```

And this... this appeared under it as well, **and I surely didn't write that!**

---

Who am I?

> Oh crap! Someone figured out my identity! My Stack Exchange profile has been compromised! 
>  Was this their plan all along?!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you are

> Batman

Reasoning

> If we reorder the characters alphabetically in the second string and use the same reordering on the first string (including spaces), it reads "I am batman." 
>  This is an example of a transposition cipher.

Comment: Hmm... I'll need to be far trickier, huh? Wanted to test the waters here.

Comment: Does "including spaces" mean the four leading spaces for a markdown code block?

Comment: @MikeTheLiar no, it does not, it means the 2 spaces after the 4 for the code-block: "  .Iaaabmmnt" (which are also shown here with quotes to emphasize them).

Comment: @MikeTheLiar you can see from how it's presented, 'b' and 'e' correspond to spaces, 'l' corresponds to '.', 'a' to 'I', etc. The corresponding characters are vertically displaced from each other.